# How to setup DataDog alerts via AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, datadog, infrastructure-as-code

Is it possible to create DataDog alerts & notifications in IaC way via AWS CDK? I want to send notifications in case of any HTTP 500 errors my web service emits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cdk-datadog-resources](https://github.com/NomadBlacky/cdk-datadog-resources) like so:

```
import { DatadogMonitor } from '@nomadblacky/cdk-datadog-resources';

new DatadogMonitor(yourStack, 'TestMonitor', {
  datadogCredentials: {
    apiKey: process.env.DATADOG_API_KEY!,
    applicationKey: process.env.DATADOG_APP_KEY!,
  },
  query: 'avg(last_1h):sum:system.cpu.system{host:host0} > 100',
  type: MonitorType.QueryAlert,
  name: 'Test Monitor',
  options: {
    thresholds: {
      critical: 100,
      warning: 80,
      oK: 90,
    },
    notifyNoData: true,
    evaluationDelay: 60,
  },
});
```

Comment: I used to think that the only one option is to use pure DataDog API. Let me try it.

Comment: Unfortunately this library hasn't been updated in 2 years and doesn't work with cdk v2 and the latest versions of the Datadog third party extension. Just warning anyone who sees this and tries to go down the route of implementing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [@goodnotes-oss/cdk-datadog-resources](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@goodnotes-oss/cdk-datadog-resources).

It's a fork of the library suggested by @miensol, but supports new Datadog Monitor versions (4.6.0) and cdk (v2).

Usage is similar. But now the credentials are configured at extension level.

```
import { DatadogMonitor } from '@nomadblacky/cdk-datadog-resources';

new DatadogMonitor(yourStack, 'TestMonitor', {
  query: 'avg(last_1h):sum:system.cpu.system{host:host0} > 100',
  type: MonitorType.QueryAlert,
  name: 'Test Monitor',
  options: {
    thresholds: {
      critical: 100,
      warning: 80,
      oK: 90,
    },
    notifyNoData: true,
    evaluationDelay: 60,
  },
});
```